# Stata Help Simulation study AR(1) model

Tags: regression, econometrics, simulation, stata

so I have a question similar to this example https://www.statalist.org/forums/forum/general-stata-discussion/general/1512656-ar-1-simulations However I don't understand how they have done the simulation, can someone please explain the simulation steps to me?

Answer (score 2):

Start by defining parameters $\beta_0$ and $\beta_1$. Then select a distribution $F$ for the error term $\epsilon_t$, for example a normal distribution in which case you have to specify mean $0$ and then select some value for the variance $\sigma^2$. Then choose some value $T$ number of timeperiods to simulate and some initial value for the process $y_0$ and set $t=1$. Then

(1) draw $\epsilon_t$ from $F$

(2) calculate $y_{t} = \beta_0 + \beta_1 y_{t-1} + \epsilon_t$

(3) add one to $t$ unless $t=T$ and go back to (1)

Comment: I posted simpler Stata code at the thread cited in the question,